# нужна помощь с несколькими "будильниками" на Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-alarm-manager

Итак, проблема в том, что не могу сообразить как создать несколько будильников, учитывая, что данные (время, дни недели) загружаются из SQLite(это принципиально). Один будильник без проблем: время из БД записывается в календарь, используется 1 `PendingIntent`, а при желании его можно отключить с помощью команды `.cancel()` и установить новый, используя этот же `PendingIntent`. Но что делать если будильников надо несколько и как различать их между собой для удаления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задавая `PendingIntent`, снабдите его уникальным номером (`unique_id`), который нужно запомнить.

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, unique_id, i, 0);
```

Позже перед удалением снова создайте  `PendingIntent` с таким же номером и отмените его.

```
alarmManager.cancel(pi);
```

Comment: я правильно понял что для удаления `PendingIntent` нужно создать якобы новый, присвоить ему тот же id что был в старом и отменить его. То есть по факту это работа со старым `PendingIntent`?

Comment: @Ivan Да, это работа с таким же 'PendingIntent'.